# Python: Calculate bearing between two lat/long

Tags: python, function, latitude-longitude, plotly-dash

I am attempting to calculate the bearing between two lat/long.

I don't have a question regarding the function/formula per se,

*provided:*

```
def get_bearing(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):
    dLon = (long2 - long1)

    y = math.sin(dLon) * math.cos(lat2)
    x = math.cos(lat1) * math.sin(lat2) - math.sin(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.cos(dLon)

    brng = math.atan2(y, x)

    brng = np.rad2deg(brng)

    return brng
```

the problem is that the result isn't what is expected.

The intended usage of the function returns the bearing between two lat/long pairs in a (very long) list i.e.

```
    lat1 = path[int(len(path) * location / 1000)][0]
    lat2 = path[int(len(path) * location / 1000) + 1][0]
    lng1 = path[int(len(path) * location / 1000)][1]
    lng2 = path[int(len(path) * location / 1000) + 1][1]
```

The bearing result then alters the view orientation of the plot where bearing can assume a value in the range [-180, 180]. Ideally, the result would appear such that the line formed between lat1, lng1 and lat2, lng2 is perfectly "vertical" in the plot (lat/lon annotations are switched in plot), *see below*

[image]

[image]

I am hoping that someone might be able to deduce the problem from the bearing returned from the function and what the expected bearing should be. A few instances below:

```
Current Location: 30.07134 -97.23076
Next in path: 30.0709 -97.22907
Calculated Bearing: 88.39967863143139
Expected Bearing: ~-70.67

Current Location: 29.91581 -96.85068
Next in path: 29.91556 -96.85021
Calculated Bearing: 118.9170342272798
Expected Bearing: ~122.67

Current Location: 29.69419 -96.53487
Next in path: 29.69432 -96.53466
Calculated Bearing 141.0271357781952
Expected Bearing: ~56

Current Location: 29.77357 -96.07924
Next in path: 29.77349 -96.07876
Calculated Bearing 165.24612555483893
Expected Bearing: ~104
```

Happy to provide additional information, thanks in advance for any/all help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ended up changing the function:

```
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic
...
def get_bearing(lat1, lat2, long1, long2):
    brng = Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(lat1, long1, lat2, long2)['azi1']
    return brng
```

Comment: This link to the docs explains the dictionary returned from `Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse` https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/1.52/python/interface.html

Answer (score 46):

Have you considered using [`pyproj`](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/) to do the calculations instead of rolling your own?:

```
import pyproj
geodesic = pyproj.Geod(ellps='WGS84')
fwd_azimuth,back_azimuth,distance = geodesic.inv(long1, lat1, long2, lat2)
```

In this example `fwd_azimuth` is the bearing you are after and `back_azimuth` is inverse bearing (going the opposite direction).

I used WGS84 here, so you would need to replace with correct coordinate system, and  need to rewrite ensure lat/long are correct type of coordinates for [`geodesic.inv()`](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/). But using a well-tested, existing geo-spatial lib will likely save you a lot of hair pulling.

Comment: I'm getting a `nan` returned for `fwd_azimuth` and that is with `float(lat)`, `float(lon)`..., etc - I would definitely like to use a geo-spatial lib but I didn't feel like dealing with idiosyncratic issues, any ideas on the `nan`?

Comment: What coordinate system are you using for your input lat/long pairs? Take a look at the [API docs for pyproj](https://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/pyproj-module.html) to see how they represent lat/long. Like I said above, you'd have to modify your code to pass in lat/long in this format.

Comment: tbh, idk - I am using Plot.ly's `ScatterMapBox` object and I can't find anything in their reference: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scattermapbox. I'm going to guess it is the same as GoogleMaps given that their API works well with `ScatterMapBox`. `Google Maps and Microsoft Virtual Earth use a Mercator projection based on the World Geodetic System (WGS) 1984 geographic coordinate system (datum).`

Comment: I found a lib (geographiclib) that I like and that works! I will upvote your answer for leading me in that direction

Comment: You have lats and longs the wrong way around, see 
https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html

in there for example: 
>>> from pyproj import Geod
>>> g = Geod(ellps='clrk66') # Use Clarke 1866 ellipsoid.
>>> boston_lat = 42.+(15./60.); boston_lon = -71.-(7./60.)
>>> portland_lat = 45.+(31./60.); portland_lon = -123.-(41./60.)
>>> # compute forward and back azimuths, plus distance
>>> # between Boston and Portland.
>>> az12,az21,dist = g.inv(boston_lon,boston_lat,portland_lon,portland_lat)
>>> "%7.3f %6.3f %12.3f" % (az12,az21,dist)
'-66.531 75.654  4164192.708'

Answer (score 10):

The code for finding the bearing is fine. But you just need to add math.radians when finding X and Y.

```
import numpy
import math

def get_bearing(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):
    dLon = (long2 - long1)
    x = math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(math.radians(dLon))
    y = math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) * math.sin(math.radians(lat2)) - math.sin(math.radians(lat1)) * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.cos(math.radians(dLon))
    brng = numpy.arctan2(x,y)
    brng = numpy.degrees(brng)

    return brng
```

Comment: The code snippet is missing imports - where are `arctan2` and `degrees` imported from, should that be numpy?

Comment: Yeah it is imported from numpy. Sorry I didnt put it there. @Wolkenarchitekt

Answer (score 2):

You can try this new package called Turfpy which is a porting of turf.js in python.

```
from turfpy import measurement
from geojson import Point, Feature
start = Feature(geometry=Point((-75.343, 39.984)))
end = Feature(geometry=Point((-75.534, 39.123)))
measurement.bearing(start,end)
```

https://pypi.org/project/turfpy/